# Create a file named with a specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Need some help here. I need to create an executable file for every user that exists on the system ( Linux ) and the format for file is the following :

```
fis_nr_username
```

where **nr** stands for 1st file, 2nd file etc...
***EXAMPLE OF SITUATION***
Users on machine :
stud01
stud02
stud03
I need a file for each of them to be executable and look like this :
file_1_stud01
file_2_stud02
file_3_stud03

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: What is a 755 file?

Comment: If `nr` ranges from 1 to 755 you could use: `username=john; for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 755); do echo "fis_${i}_${username}"; done`. To create the file replace `echo` with `touch`

Comment: @Sergio it s a relative small number of users, max 30 nothing too shabby but after i saw your reply i was going in the wrong direction with my logic, thanks for help

Comment: @Sergio the thing I am not allowed to input my username from keyboard, i m supposed to somehow get it from terminal, using whoami or something like that, that s my problem X_X

Comment: What are the numbers supposed to be? Please, please edit your question and explain more, show us some sample file names, *something*.

Comment: @JohnKugelman this is a situation
Users on machine :
stud01
stud02
stud03
I need a file for each of them to be executable and look like this :
file_1_stud01
file_2_stud02
file_3_stud03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the user list, then loop through file number (here 0 to 10). Use printf with `%03d` to pad with zeros.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                     

username="stud01 stud02 stud03"                                                              
for name in $username; do                                                                                                             
    for ((i=0; i<11; i++)); do                                                                                                        
      printf "file_%03d_%s\n" $i $name                                                                                                 
    done                                                                                                                              
done
```

---

You could make this a function and put it in `.bashrc`

```
newfiles() {                                                                                                                                      
  username="$@"                                                              
  for name in $username; do                                                                                                             
      for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do                                                                                                        
        printf "file_%03d_%s\n" $i $name                                                                                                 
      done                                                                                                                              
  done
}
```

call the function from terminal with: `newfiles firstuser serconduser`. Output:

```
fis_000_firstuser
fis_001_firstuser
fis_002_firstuser
fis_000_seconduser
fis_001_seconduser
fis_002_seconduser
```

Comment: The problem is that i do not need a specific algorithm, i need an more general version of what you wrote there, that s what troubles me otherwise i would have not posted :))